# knockout "observable is not a function" when declaring a datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

In the html I have this `select`:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="datepicker: StartDate" />
```

It's not inside of a loop.  Just a standalone.  And inside the knockout model, I am trying to define it as follows:

```
function VacationRequestsViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.StartDate = new Date();
    ....
}
```

And this too....

```
$(document).on('ready',
    function () {
        masterVM = new VacationRequestsViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(masterVM);
    });
```

On page load, I get this

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "datepicker: function (){return StartDate }"
>   Message: observable is not a function

I have successfully declared lots of other things.  Observable's.  ObservableArray's   Bool's.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Based on the error message I'm guessing the datepicker binding is expecting StartDate to be an observable. Try declaring it as "self.StartDate = ko.observable(new Date());"

Comment: thanks!  trying that

Comment: that was it.  I was reading the error message wrong. I thought I had it as a funciton when it shouldn't have been.  If you make that an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message I'm guessing the datepicker binding is expecting StartDate to be an observable. Try declaring it as `self.StartDate = ko.observable(new Date());`